# 'GL/gl.h' file not found in QT Creator 5.12.5

Tags: qt, opengl

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04. The "include" statement drop an error like QT doesn't find the libraries of GL but I installed them.

I already tried a lot of commands that I saw but none of them worked. I'm sorry I can give more info.
[The line 13 drop the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBbJm.png)

Comment: did you tried changing the location of gl library to where all the header are installed ?

Comment: you might also like to see the answers give here at Qt forums https://forum.qt.io/topic/50865/gl-gl-h-not-found-in-linux